# Bash escape postgres password

Tags: postgresql, bash, escaping

Having problems connecting to my db with psql.

I have a weird password

```
@efszP&\\39D7"d_
```

Im having hard time escaping it,tried like this :

```
psql postgres://USERNAMER:"\@efszP\&\\\\39D7\"d_"@HOST:5432/DB_NAME
```

Getting this ERROR

```
psql: error: could not translate host name "efszP\&\\39D7"d_@ENDPOINT" to address: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Try replacing `@` with `%40` (and check the spelling of _weird)._

Comment: so  %40efszP\&\\\\39D7\"d_ ? 
didnt work unfortunately

Comment: I don't see why you would backslash the ampersand, but there are many things here which are down to guesswork.

Comment: Thanks ! removed the backslash for the ampersand and it fixed it !

Comment: hey,can you help me again ^_^ .. with :  ?A$5d&9Sy{F*fWZ(

Answer (score 0):

You could try the URL encoded password as %40efszP%26%5C%5C39D7%22d_.